# ajax call PHP script with jQuery showing status

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am learning jQuery recently and trying to do an ajax call to a very simple PHP script, which just output 1 json text. When I just have 1 `echo` statement in my script, I was able to get the call working. I then tried to mimic a complex script by `echo` 4 json after sleep for 3 seconds each time, but this time I could not be able to make it work.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>ajax</title>
          <script src="jquery.js"></script>
          <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="loading"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#loading').html('<img src="http://preloaders.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "x.php",
        dataType: "json"
    });
    req.done(function(data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#loading').html(data.text);
                                        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Here is my x.php:

```
<?php
    sleep(3);
    echo json_encode(array("text"=>"you got me1"));
    sleep(3);
    echo json_encode(array("text"=>"you got me2"));
    sleep(3);
    echo json_encode(array("text"=>"you got me3"));
    sleep(3);
    echo json_encode(array("text"=>"you got me4"));
?>
```

My purpose is trying to show 'you got me1', 'you got me2'...one by one after few seconds. Could anyone please help and tell me where I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your current approach won't work, since the php page will show all json arrays at once (when it has sleeped the time between the encoding and after all the encoding and such). Your best bet would be to make several ajax calls, I believe.

Comment: Yeah, unless you can flush the buffer in between sleeps, it'll just come back on 1 request after 12 seconds or so.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think the json would be output one by one? `sleep` did mean the code was paused? I am trying to mimic some long running process...

Comment: Yes, paused but the HTTP request isn't "finished" until it has processed the entire script unless you manually return it early.

Comment: oops...yes it's, if I visit `x.php` it output all json after 12 sec...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php might help, but from the comments it sounds like it might not... too long since I've done much PHP to be much more help I'm afraid :)

Comment: This behavior would have to occur Client Side, if you just want an meaningless pause. Use `setInterval()` with `clearInterval()`.

Comment: I agree with PHPglue.  it doesnt make sense to echo your output from php more than once.  you can create a timer that loops a few times and make more ajax requests.  One ajax request, one result.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I was wondering is anyone have examples that showing updating script status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON must be a monolithic string. You cannot output four separate JSON constructs in a single response. e.g.

```
$x = array('foo');
$y = array('bar');
$z = array('baz');

echo json_encode($x);
echo json_encode($y);
echo json_encode($z);
```

Will send

```
['foo']['bar']['baz']
```

across the wire. That is NOT syntactically valid JSON and will simplyl produce a parse error on the receiving end.

If you want to send 4 different chunks of data over as JSON, you'll either have to do four separate requests, or embed each response in a sub-array, e.g.

```
$response = array(
  'x' => array('foo'),
  'y' => array('bar'),
  'z' => array('baz')
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Remember that JSON is (almost exactly) the same as the "right-hand side" of a variable assignment in Javascript:

```
var foo = XXX;
          ^^^---json goes here
```

If you want your output to be accepted, you have to generate something that you could literally paste into that assignment operation and have the JS engine parse/execute it properly, so

```
var response = ['foo']['bar']['baz']; // syntax error
var response = [['foo'],['bar'],['baz']]; // syntactically valid
```